# How do I pass a function (written externally) and allocate to a column in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, function

```
def calc1(tentative_valuations, previous_buying_price):
  return tentative_valuations - previous_buying_price

#mortgage calculator
def calc2(loanper, previous_buying_price):
  return loanper * previous_buying_price



#indicative paid interest to date **REQUIRES ACCESSOR** ###################
calc3 = int(lookups((ym_between(b, a)[0]), (ym_between(b, a)[1]), 'Cum Interest Paid'))


# #net indicative capital gain today #######################################
calc4 = calc1(tentative_valuations, previous_buying_price) - calc3
#print(calc4)


# #to calculate psf before
def calc5(previous_buying_price, area):
  return previous_buying_price/area

# #to calculate psf after
def calc6(tentative_valuations, area):
  return tentative_valuations/area


#print(calc5(previous_buying_price,area))
#print(calc6(tentative_valuations, area))

# #annualised ##########################################
def calc7():
  return round((((calc6(tentative_valuations, area)/calc5(previous_buying_price, area))**(1/(ym_between(b,a)[0]+ ym_between(b,a)[1]/12))) - 1)*100,2)
#no problem
#print(calc7())

#indicative paid principal to date
calc8 = int(lookups((ym_between(b, a)[0]), (ym_between(b, a)[1]), 'Cumulative Paid Principal'))

#indicative balance 
calc9 = (loanper * previous_buying_price) - calc8
```

```
  #create the dataframe.
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Gross Indicative Capital Gain Today', 'Net Indicative Capital Gain Today','Indicative Average Gross Annual Capital Gain', 'Indicative Paid Principal to Date ', 'Indicative Paid Interest to Date',
                        'Indicative Balance'])
    df2['Gross Indicative Capital Gain Today'] = calc1(tentative_valuations, previous_buying_price)
    df2['Net Indicative Capital Gain Today'] = calc3
    df2['Indicative Average Gross Annual Capital Gain'] = calc7()
    df2['Indicative Paid Principal to Date'] = calc8
    df2['Indicative Paid Interest to Date'] = calc3
    df2['Indicative Balance'] = calc9
    df2.head()
```

when i call df2, nothing seems to appear only the headers? all the calc are either variables or functions that have output. Rather new to pandas (my 2nd day learning), would appreciate the help thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot assign types like, int, bool to specific columns in a data frame like that you have surround it in an array like this:

```py
df2['Indicative Paid Principal to Date'] = [calc8]
```

if you want to add values to a new row you can do this

```py
new_values = [calc1(tentative_valuations, previous_buying_price), calc3, calc7, calc8, calc3, calc9]
df2.loc[0] = new_values
```

Comment: thank you that did the trick. do you have any suggested guides that could prove useful to a pandas noob like me haha?

Comment: @CodingMemes I'm assuming your using, jupyterlab or jupyter notebook, so I would also have a console window open which you can open by clicking the "+" in jupyter lab where you can test out ideas to make sure they work, and then just google every question you have about how to do something. Most questions you will ever have have already been answered on stack or elsewhere. you can look into the documentation for different parameters of functions and classes That will tend to give you a good description what stuff does. It will be slow going at first buteventually you won't need google anymore

Answer (score 0):

Calling df2 directly won't do anything.

Change the last line to this:

```
print(df2)
```

Comment: my output only shows headers of the respective columns, not the values. im using colabs to do this so calling df2 merely shows the dataframe.